# Master slave replication with replica latency in mind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, master-slave

I am working on a Ruby on rails application in production.

This application needs master/slave database replication.

I am using the [octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) gem to do that.

The problem is that I have a staging env working for the past week or so, in that staging env I have setup alerts on amazon RDS.

I see that the replica latency is sometimes 10 seconds (it's even 100 seconds sometimes).

How would you handle that in your application, thinking that I have several instances running, all under a load balancer, and I also have background jobs running (using Resque)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple `master/slave` replication of data, have you considered doing this at the database rather than application level.

I run several `master/slave` and `master/master` setups using `MySQL` replication, which tends to keep the replication latency very low on a reasonably fast `WAN connection`. It's not synchronous, but it sounds like that's not a requirement in this case.